# Wrapping Boot call in a function produces an error

Tags: r

In `R`, generate some fake data:

```
x1 <- runif(100)
y1 <- 2*x1 + runif(100)
```

Produce a linear model and pass it to `Boot` (from the `car` package)

```
fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
Boot(fit1)
```

No problem.  Now wrap this same code in a function.

```
do_boot <- function(x,y) {
  fit <- lm(y ~ x)
  Boot(fit)
}
do_boot(x1,y1)
```

This produces an error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I cannot explain (maybe because how works internally `Boot`) you need to have your data in the global environment. See the error:

You can either assign your data to the global environment:

```
library(car)

x1 <- runif(100)
y1 <- 2*x1 + runif(100)

do_boot <- function(x,y) {
  assign("x",x,envir=parent.frame())
  assign("y",y,envir=parent.frame())
  fit <- lm(y ~ x)
  Boot(fit)
  rm(x)
  rm(y)
}

do_boot(x1,y1)
```

Or use those directly:

```
library(car)

x1 <- runif(100)
y1 <- 2*x1 + runif(100)

do_boot <- function() {
  fit <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
  Boot(fit)

}

do_boot()
```

For me, both solutions are weird and uggly. I prefer the first one, though.

Comment: I suspected it was something like that.  But so weird that `Boot` is written in such a way that the data must be in the global environment.  That strikes me as very poor design.